# IONIC 2: Background opacity affect to ion-content images

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I´m trying to set an image as a background for ion-content of a ionic page, I need this image degraded, so with opacity I put it 0.6 and it works.

```
Ion-content {
    Background-image: url ('../assets/back/2.jpg');
    -webkit-background-image: url ('../assets/back/2.jpg');
    Opacity: 0.50;
}
```

But the problem is that it also applies apha to the images that I show in grid within ion-content.

The question: how do I change the opacity of the background image without also affecting the opacity of the images I want to display in ion-content, as content?

Comment: why not override opacity in the ion-grid class in the css?

Comment: Hi Suraj. Good point, I'll try that and comment later. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Suraj. Don't work. The Opacity level that I define for one component, affects to child components that are inside. I ask same in Ionic forums but don't have response yet.

Comment: did u find the solution ?